# Typescript: Definition files and globals

Tags: typescript

Almost all definition files so readily available you know where, do a `declare module` or `declare var`. Isn't this a huge problem? If I forget to import an implementation of a declared module and then use it, compiler will never give me an error, but the app will crash horribly at run time.

One way I see how to solve this is to write definition files only with a `declare module "topLevelName"`, so you can't accidentally use it without requiring it first. But this creates a problem for things such as jQuery, because people tend to not `require` it but just put it into global context. In this case current approach is actually working correctly.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around this huge limitation of the system. Am I missing something?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't verify that all of the compiled output files are actually included on the page either, since there could be a `a.ts` and `b.ts`, but the page contains only `<script src="a.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I forget to import an implementation of a declared module and then use it, compiler will never give me an error, but the app will crash horribly at run time.

Yes

> Isn't this a huge problem

Not really. The likelyhood of adding a types but forgetting to include the JavaScript is not very high with beginner level experience.

> Am I missing something?

no.

## More

A bigger problem is type compatability between libs e.g different TypeScript libraries depending up different editions of JQuery.

Comment: When you are structuring your app using CommonJS or AMD the likelihood of forgetting to `require` a file is very high, since you have to do it in each file that uses that specific library. The likelihood of forgetting to include a script tag is certainly very small, but that is only if you are okay with globals (and/or not working with NodeJS). I'll accept your answer because it's seems your point of view is being shared among most Typescript developers.